# Как в scala извлечь данные из результата запроса к mongodb?

Tags: json, scala, mongo

Создал из scala подключение к БД на mongodb. Подключилось успешно, код такой:

```scala
  val config = ConfigFactory.load().getConfig("akka")
  implicit val system = ActorSystem("asl", config)

  val uri = "mongodb://mnguser:123@localhost:27017"

  val mongoClientSettings = MongoClientSettings.builder().applyConnectionString(ConnectionString(uri))
    .serverApi(ServerApi.builder().version(ServerApiVersion.V1).build())
    .build()

  val client = MongoClient(mongoClientSettings)
  val database = client.getDatabase("magazine")

  val collection: MongoCollection[Document] = database.getCollection("article")

//  val result = collection.find().first  // Здесь бы выбрать результат в читаемом виде
```

Внутри монги лежат документы вот в таком виде:

```json
{
  _id":{"$oid":"623190cb6a1c5c237f93a63c"}
  "article": "Основы биологии",
  "version": "1.1.0.0",
  "download": "some_link_here"
}
```

Мне нужно выбрать все статьи, причем каждая статья должна быть последней версии, т.е. если есть три документа "Основы биологии" с версиями "1.1.0.0.", "1.12.0.0", "2.0.0.1", то должен выбраться документ с версией "2.0.0.1" как самый новый, аналогично с другими статьями. И отдать результат в json.

Если целиком такая задача слишком сложна, помогите хотя бы фрагментом кода по извлечению данных. Например, в массив\список объектов с полями article, version, download.

Answer (score 0):

Задачу в итоге решил. Получилось не совсем в scala-стиле, зато работает. Если кто-то сможет поправить, чтобы было красивее, welcome.

1. Создаем класс для хранения информации о статьях:

```scala
case class ArticleInfo(article: String, version: String, download: String) {
  override def toString(): String = "[article='" + article+ "', version='" + version + "', download='" + download+ "']"
}
```

2. Вот этим фрагментом можно извлечь данные из коллекции. Сначала выбираем все документы, превращаем их в объекты. Потом непосредственно извлекаем с помощью Await.result, получаем Seq со строками:

```scala
val sel = collection.find(Document())
  .map(dbo => ArticleInfo(
    dbo.getString("article"),
    dbo.getString("version"),
    dbo.getString("download")))

Await.result[Seq[ArticleInfo]](sel.toFuture(), Duration.Inf)
```

3. Вот такой класс понадобится, чтобы дать методу сортировки алгоритм сравнения версий наших статей:

```scala
object VersionOrdering extends Ordering[ArticleInfo] {
  override def compare(x: ArticleInfo, y: ArticleInfo): Int = {
    var xNums: Array[Int] = x.version.split("\\.").map(_.toInt);
    var yNums: Array[Int] = y.version.split("\\.").map(_.toInt);

    for (i <- 0 to xNums.size) {
      if (xNums(i) < yNums(i))
        return -1
      if (yNums(i) < xNums(i))
        return 1
    }

    return 0
  }
}
```

Ну и наконец вот демо получения сортированных статей. Только вместо тестового набора данных подставляем данные из базы, полученные в пункте 2.

```scala
object SortTest {
  def test: Unit = {
    // Сгруппируем статьи по названию, чтобы одинаковые попали в единый Seq
    val articles: Map[String, Seq[ArticleInfo]] = getAllArticles.groupBy(_.name)

    // В этот массив будем складывать по одному экземпляру каждой статьи (свежий)
    val arr = new Array[ArticleInfo](articles.size)
    var i = 0
    for (article <- articles) {
      // _2 - это keys словаря, у нас там набор статей одного вида, но разных версий
      arr(i) = getLatest(article._2)
      i+=1
    }

    arr.foreach(println(_))
  }

  private def getLatest(history: Seq[ArticleInfo]): ArticleInfo = {
    var arr = history.toArray
    // Сортировка по возрастанию, значит самая свежая будет в конце
    arr.sorted(VersionOrdering).last
  }

  private def getAllArticles: Seq[ArticleInfo] = {
    Seq(
      ArticleInfo("Основы биологии", "2.19.1.3", "link_here"),
      ArticleInfo("Птицы нашего края", "12.0.4.5", "link_here"),
      ArticleInfo("Ядовитые грибы", "3.22", "link_here"),
      ArticleInfo("Основы биологии", "12.0.9.7", "link_here")
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: в целом норм, только а) версия не оптимальна (группировку логично производить на уровне БД, но в данном случае это сложно или даже не возможно) б) не используй `var` там, где легко обойтись `val` в) группировка логична по id.$oid, т.к. в теории могут быть разные статьи с одинаковым названием г) для нахождения максимума вовсе не обязательно сортировать массив, достаточно вызывать `max` или `maxBy` -- сложность поиска максимума намного меньше сложности сортировки